# Access sever loaded config from react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've had a good look around but I can't quite construct a search to get any relevant results.

What is the best way to load in a config object that is generated from the server when it isn't possible to call an API?

The config is printed to the page like so:

```
var config = {configItem: 'configAnswer', ...etc }
```

Then in react I'm literally reaching in and accessing it as normal

```
const item = config.configItem;
```

This may be fine it just doesn't seem very 'react like'.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Example of component code. As you can see `product.handle` is coming from a server generated global variable.

```
const Cart = class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { cartLoaded: false, cart: {} };
  }
  getCart = async () => {
    const cart = await fetch(`/products/${product.handle}.js`);
    const json = await cart.json();
    this.setState({ cartLoaded: true, cart: json });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.cartLoaded === false) {
      this.getCart();
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.cartLoaded === false) {
      return null;
    }
    return <div className="purchase-container"></div>;
  }
};
```

Comment: you want to do do something when you can't request something to API? Like when there's no internet connection?

Comment: @MatheusReis no the config is generated from the server. In this case its shopify (Ruby).

Comment: Okay. You want to know how to proccess the data received? If yes, can you show what component use it?

Comment: @MatheusReis no problem with processing it, I would just like to know a more 'react' way of accessing the data ( instead of reaching into the DOM )... If there is one

Comment: so, show your component code, then I can help you

Comment: @MatheusReis added an example of a component as requested. Thank you